# Show NoData message on HighStock graph

Tags: html, highcharts

I'm looking for a native way to display a message over an Highstock graph when there is no data to display or when an error occurs. In fact, I knew that the [noData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData)  solution already exists for the Highchart library but it seems that it is not yet implemented in Highstock...

So, does anybody knows how to achieve this other than showing a message in a different div?

Thank you in advance for your time! 
Keven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after few days on UserVoice an administrator told me that the noData functionality is also available under Highstock (this functionality is not currently described in the API documentation).

This is the link of the admin reply (including a jsfiddle demo) :
https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/8547274-highstock-display-a-message-when-nodata-is-avail

This is the link of the API reference (Highchart references) : 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your own solution, based on extracting series object from highcharts. Then you check data length and show div or not.

```
if(series[0].data.length === 0) {
    $('#nodata').show();
}    

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {},
    series: series
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/125/

Comment: I've already implemented this kind of work around but it's not the prettiest way. I've just created a new post on uservoice to implement the functionnality. Please vote at will!  https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/8547274-highstock-display-a-message-when-nodata-is-avail thanks